# Help to understand differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I don't understand the following differentiation.
$$g(t)=f(\mathbf x_0+t(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0))\\g'(t)=\nabla f(\mathbf x_0+t(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0))\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0)$$
I know it follows from the chain rule, but I just don't understand it. Hope someone can explain.

Comment: Thank you have been edited.

Comment: Do you see how we can express $g(t)$ as $g(t) = f(h(t))$? What is $h(t)$? So then the multivariable chain rule tells us that $g'(t) = f'(h(t)) h'(t)$. What's $h'(t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$, as well as two points ${\bf p}_0$, ${\bf p}\in{\mathbb R}^n$. Now an auxiliary $t$-scale is laid onto the line $\ell:={\bf p}_0\vee{\bf p}$, whereby $t=0$ at ${\bf p}_0$, and $t=1$ at ${\bf p}$. In the sequel you are only interested in the values of $f$ along $\ell$. Given the $t$-scale on $\ell$ these values can be considered as a function of the single real variable $t$ in the following way:
$$g(t):=f\bigl({\bf p}_0+t({\bf p}-{\bf p}_0)\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$You could plot the function $g$ as in precalc in a $(t,y)$ coordinate system. The function $g$ will have a derivative with respect to $t$, and this derivative can be calculated from $(1)$ using the chain rule.

If $f$ is given as a concrete expression in the coordinate variables $x_i$ then you can also simply plug in $x_i:=(1-t)p^{0}_i + t p_i$ into $f$ and obtain $g$ as a complicated expression in $t$ whose origins are no longer visible, as in $(1)$. Now differentiate $g$ with respect to its single variable $t$.